# Apple Music Offline Files on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, audio, music.app, mp3

I have mp3 files for a few albums, all in a folder. When I drag/drop that folder into the Apple Music app, it adds it to the library. I can also use the "Automatically add to music" folder.

If I update the contents of the folder (the one with my music), for example I add/remove music, how do I make it reflect across the app (other than manually deleting, and re-importing the files)?

If this is not possible, are there other ways to listen to music when you have the files, on Mac and iPhone? (preferably clean UI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I update the contents of the folder (the one with my music), for example I add/remove music, how do I make it reflect across the app (other than manually deleting, and re-importing the files)?

Use Apple Music for the file management.

When you delete an entry in Apple Music, it will ask you if you want to just remove it from the library or remove and delete the associated file.

Personally, I use [Strawberry Music Player](https://www.strawberrymusicplayer.org/) because it’s an open source and cross platform HighRes music player.  Since I prefer to listen to music on my Sony Walkman NW-A55, this player allows me to manage my library and playlists that work with both my Walkman and Apple Music.  For the rare times I use my iPhone for music, I simply choose to selectively sync playlists and not my whole library.

Comment: What if I accidentally delete an entry?

Are there other music players with a clean UI?

Comment: I’m not clear on what you “if you delete an entry.”  How?  In Apple Music?  Manually?  As far as layers, I wanted one that handled FLAC, multiple playlist formats, could sync to USB storage and was  cross platform. The UI works for me.  Try [Colibri](https://colibri-lossless.com/). The UI looks clean but the focus is Lossless audio.

Comment: I meant accidentally delete an entry in the apple music app. If it was file based, I can command z but not on the app
Colibri - I also need it to work on iPhone

Comment: Then you want something that syncs the iTuned/Music library.  There are a couple of apps that do this, but unfortunately I can’t remember their names.  I found them on the app store, but since they didn’t meet my needs, I moved on. I do know they exist, however.